# why I am not able to initialize array of pointers providing 2d array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, anonymous

[image]

```
int *p = ( int[] ){ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

Doing this I am able to initialize a anonymous `array` to a pointer `p`.
In a similar way I want to assign arrays of array (i.e. probably 2D array) in
array of pointers. And so I have tried the following code:

```
int *p[]= (int [][3]) { {1,2,3},{10,20,30} };
```

But it goes wrong, anyway if I assign it to a pointer to whole Array( as  `int (*p)[]= (int [][3]) { {1,2,3},{10,20,30} };` ) it works fine.
I am in confused that if a pointer can get assigned a anonymous array why the array of pointers could not get assigned to 2d array?

Comment: Please elaborate "it goes wrong" and provide a [mre] each for  both described cases. Also pleas explain what you intend to do this way. I suspect that there is a better way. Compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: If X is a type, then an array of X [decays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay) to a pointer of X. Now say X is array-of-Y. An array of X still decays to a pointer to X, that is, a pointer to an array-of-Y. It does not decay to an array of pointers to anything, nor to a pointer to a pointer to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal)

```
(int [][3]) { {1,2,3},{10,20,30} };
```

has the type

```
int [2][3]
```

i.e. array of 2 elements, each consisting of 3 `int` elements.

When used in the line

```
int *p[]= (int [][3]) { {1,2,3},{10,20,30} };
```

the array will [decay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/12149471) to a pointer to the first element. This pointer will therefore have the type "pointer to array of 3 `int` elements`.

However, you cannot assign this data type to `p`, because the types are different. You declared `p` as an array of pointers. That is why your code is not working.

If you want `p` to be an array of pointers in which every pointer points to its array of `int` elements, then you will need to use several compound literals, one for each of these arrays:

```
int *p[] = {
    ( int[] ){  1,  2,  3,  4 },
    ( int[] ){  5,  6,  7,  8 },
    ( int[] ){  9, 10, 11, 12 }
};
```

Here is a small test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int *p[] = {
        ( int[] ){  1,  2,  3,  4 },
        ( int[] ){  5,  6,  7,  8 },
        ( int[] ){  9, 10, 11, 12 }
    };

    printf( "%d\n", p[1][2] );
}
```

This program has the output `7`.

**EDIT:**

According to your remarks in the comments section of this answer, it seems that you have several 2D arrays and want to create an array of pointers to these arrays. In that case, you can do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    //define first 2D array
    int arr1[][4] = {
        {  1,  2,  3,  4},
        {  5,  6,  7,  8},
        {  9, 10, 11, 12}
    };

    //define second 2D array
    int arr2[][4] = {
        { 13,  14, 15, 16},
        { 17,  18, 19, 20},
        { 21,  22, 23, 24}
    };

    //define array of 2 pointers that point to the first
    //rows of arr1 and arr2
    int (*p[])[4] = { arr1, arr2 };

    //use pointer array to get the 4th element in the
    //3rd row of the second 2D array
    printf( "%d\n", p[1][2][3] );
}
```

This program will give you the correct output `24`.

If you find the declaration `int (*p[])[4]` hard to understand, then you may want to read [this page](https://www.codementor.io/@dankhan/how-to-easily-decipher-complex-pointer-declarations-cpp-so24b66me) on how these declarations are to be interpreted. Also, [this site](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*p%5B%5D%29%5B4%5D) may be useful.

You can also simplify your declarations by using a [typedef](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/typedef), so that the type `arrow_row` represents an array of 4 `int` elements (i.e. a row of a 2D array) like this:

```
typedef int array_row[4];
```

Now, you can simplify the declaration

```
int (*p[])[4] = { arr1, arr2 };
```

to:

```
array_row *p[] = { arr1, arr2 };
```

Comment: Doing this, Your are assigning different 1D arrays to an array of pointers. Thanks for this. Also suggest me how could I assign 2D array in an array of pointers.

Comment: @AnupAdhikari: How exactly do you want a 2D array assigned to an array of pointers? Do you want every element of the array of pointers to point to the start of a row in the 2D array?

Comment: yeah , all I was saying exactly the same you are taking about so that I could access 2D array

Comment: @AnupAdhikari: You can construct such an array of pointers in a loop. See [this working code example](https://godbolt.org/z/azsPvM6nh). You could also hard-code the pointer array, like this: `int *p[] = { arr[0], arr[1], arr[2] };`, but then you would have to change this definition whenever the number of rows changes. If you use the code I posted in the link, then it will adapt to the number of lines automatically, and you will never have to change the definition of `p`.

Comment: @AnupAdhikari: Note that what you are asking for is rather strange. I therefore suspect that you are asking about an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You may want to explain what your ultimate goal is.

Comment: It is not a kind of XY problem or whatever it is, the actual problem is I have several 2D arrays and instead of creating pointers one by one, I wanna create array of such pointers which is capable of pointing all my 2D Arrays. And how many 2D Array is not constant and so I want implicit declaration instead assigning subsequently.

Comment: The commented line states that I have assigned a 2D array to a pointer but I want array of such pointers which could store numbers of 2D Array.

Comment: @AnupAdhikari: In your previous comment, you wrote: "but I want array of such pointers which could store numbers of 2D Array" -- This statement does not make sense. A pointer cannot "store numbers", it can only point to "numbers".

Comment: @AnupAdhikari: I have now added another program to the bottom of my answer, which defines two 2D arrays and creates an array of two pointers which each point to one of the 2D arrays.

Comment: Andreas Wenzel, Thanks exactly the same I was seeking for. Also suggest me, `char *p="String Literal";`  with this statement I am able to assign the string to the pointer variable now suppose I want a character to assign without declaring variable for character as I did in string than is there some way? If yes then please let me know.

Comment: @AnupAdhikari: I am not sure if this is what you want, but you can create a `char` as a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) (i.e. as an anonymous variable) and then initialize a pointer `p` to point to that `char`, like this: `char *p = &(char){'A'};` However, this is a very strange thing to do. I have never seen anyone ever do this. Why do you want to do this? I suspect that there is a better way to achieve your ultimate goal.

Answer (score 1):

`int *p[]` is an array of pointers, not a pointer to an array.

You'll need to do:

```
int (*p)[3]= (int [][3]) { {1,2,3},{10,20,30} };
```

The reason why is that an array, whenever used in an expression, decays into a pointer to the first element. So no matter the array type, your pointer will need to correspond to the pointer to the first element.

In case of an `int[]`, the element type is `int` and a pointer to it would be `int*`.

In case of an `int[][3]`, the element type is `int[3]` and a pointer to it would be `int (*p)[3]`.

Comment: Please have a look at my image too. All I am saying is that if I can assign a array or address of an array(whatever it treats internally) to a pointer (p) why can't I assign a collection of those array which is in fact 2D array in a array of similar pointers.

Comment: @AnupAdhikari Because in that case you need to do `int* p [] = { arr[0], arr[1], ...}` which would be a rather cumbersome and generally pointless array to have.

Comment: Good to say that `int (*p)[] = (int [][3]) { {1,2,3},{10,20,30} };` is also valid, is a pointer to an array with unspecified bounds, as such you can not use `sizeof` nor dereference this kind of pointers without a cast, in your case `((int (*)[3])p)[1][1]` will give you 20.

Comment: @Lundin could you please elaborate and show me coding

Comment: @DavidRanieri  could you please elaborate and show me coding?

Comment: @DavidRanieri Yes but I omitted that for pedagogic reasons, since the decayed pointer to the first element is a `int(*)[3]` and not a `int(*)[]`.